# Send push notification to multiple devices in single HTTP request with different data for each device using FCM & PHP

Tags: php, http, firebase-cloud-messaging

As per the official document, we can send push notification to multiple devices using a topic or device group. But the problem is it needs a common message and payload data for all devices.

I want to send different messages to all devices.

> For example, below users should receive the following message on their
>   devices.
>
> **User Amit:** Hello Amit, your request approved.
>
> **User Sandip:** Hello Sandip, your request declined.
>
> **User Piyush:** Hello Piyush, your request declined.
>
> And so on..... to 200-300 users.

Is it possible to send this all messages in a single HTTP request using Firebase Cloud Messaging?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible with the official Admin SDKs (see https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send_a_batch_of_messages), but unfortunately, the REST API documentation doesn't include information on how to send batch requests (yet, at least I didn't find them so far), probably because it involves creating a special kind of multipart request and is not easy to set up.

So I would advise using an Admin SDK to do it. As I don't know how you've sent the messages in the past, please be warned that using an Admin SDK comes with some additional setup (e.g. creating/downloading a Service Account), compared to making "just" a cURL request.

So, if you don't *have* to use PHP, it's always wiser to use one of the official SDKs (see https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup/)

If you *do* choose to stick with PHP, there is an unofficial Admin SDK for PHP at https://github.com/kreait/firebase-php that supports sending batch messages. (Disclaimer: I'm the maintainer of that SDK).

You can read more about it in the repo or specifically at https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cloud-messaging.html#send-multiple-messages-at-once, but here is how it *might* look like for your situation if you decided to give the PHP SDK a try:

```php
use Kreait\Firebase\Factory;
use Kreait\Firebase\Messaging\CloudMessage;
use Kreait\Firebase\Messaging\Notification;
use Kreait\Firebase\ServiceAccount;

$serviceAccount = ServiceAccount::fromJsonFile('/path/to/service_account.json');

$users = [
    ['name' => 'Amit', 'is_approved' => true, 'registration_token' => '...'],
    ['name' => 'Sandip', 'is_approved' => false, 'registration_token' => '...'],
    ['name' => 'Piyush', 'is_approved' => true, 'registration_token' => '...'],
    // ...
];

$messages = [];

foreach ($users as $user) {
    $statusText = $user['is_approved'] ? 'approved' : 'denied';

    $messages[] = CloudMessage::withTarget('token', $user['registration_token'])
        ->withNotification([
            'title' => "Your request was {$statusText}",
            'body' => "Hello {$user['name']}! Your request was {$statusText}.", 
        ]);
}

$messaging = (new Factory())
    ->withServiceAccount($serviceAccount)
    ->createMessaging();

$sendReport = $messaging->sendAll($messages);

echo 'Successful sends: '.$sendReport->successes()->count().PHP_EOL;
echo 'Failed sends: '.$sendReport->failures()->count().PHP_EOL;
```

I hope this helps!